# Adding reference to a class library at runtime in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, plugins, microservices, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I've created an asp.net core 5  empty web application with one class library that is a simple controller used for view model composition. The class is as below:

```
 public class MarketingProductInfo : ICompositionRequestsHandler
    {
        [HttpGet("/product/{id}")]
        public Task Handle(HttpRequest request)
        {
            var vm = request.GetComposedResponseModel();

            //retrieve product details from the marketing database or service
            vm.ProductName = "Name";
            vm.ProductDescription = "This is a sample product";

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Actually this library is going to be a microservice that returns data for a specefic route.
Now when i add a reference to class library at compile time, everything works fine and by using postman i can get a response from the Web app.
The problem is that i want this referencing happen at runtime. So for example i copy the dll files of class libraries in a folder and the web app loads them at runtime for sake of modularity.
I searched alot in the internet about plugins and etc. but everything i've found was loading a dll and executing a specific method or instantiating a class...
My questions is how i can load this dll at runtime without need for doing anything else?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to add a reference at runtime, for any specific reason?
If you don't want to have a direct reference to the library for the sack of modularity, then you can take advantage of Nuget.

1. Push class library as NuGet package.
2. Add that NuGet package to your web app project.

This way you don't have a direct dependency on your class library and you can manage those both separately!

Comment: I want to have modularity at runtime for user not developer, meaning he/she can add modules to the website or remove them.

Comment: Have a look at this -> https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2020/Trailblazor-Building-Dynamic-Applications-with-Blazor